# Drawing to dot in networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I am using `networkx`, with my own custom `Node` class. When I run `nx.write_dot(G, "graph.py")`, I get the node object in the output, as such:

```
strict graph {
    graph [bb="0,0,289.87,36"];
    node [label="\N"];
    "<node.Node object at 0x10425f550>"  [height=0.5,
        pos="144.94,18",
        width=4.026];
}
```

How can I make `networkx` output the relevant attribute? My `Node` class has an `id` field that I want it to be labeled by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within

```
class Node:
```

implement

```
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Node(id={0.id})".format(self)
```

This tells python how to `repr`esent your class.

Comment: Thank you, this saved me a lot of time.

Comment: On a related note, do you happen to know how to label edges in networkx so that the labels show up in the dot file?

Comment: I think you need one of the other drawing options: http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/drawing.html